# Setting meta:resourcekey on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have a label on a page which gets localized text through the `meta:resourcekey` attribute.  The issue I have is that I want it to display different text depending on which view of a multiview they're on.

I tried adding the attribute though `label.Attributes.Add("meta:resourcekey", "label")`, but that doesn't seem to load any text.  I tried it on `PreRender`, and same deal. The attribute appears when I look at the source, but no text is displayed.

Is this possible to do?  The other option is to have 2 labels and change the visibility on page load, but that seems like the less elegant solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Does "they're" in "view of a multiview they're on." refer to the label, the user, or something else?

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want for programmatic localisation in code behind is as simple as this:

```
ctrl.Text = (string)GetLocalResourceObject(“myCtrlKey.Text”);
ctrl.AnotherAttribute = (string)GetLocalResourceObject(“myCtrlKey.AnotherAttribute”);
```

Using LocalResource means that for a page called MyPage.aspx, you have created a resource file called MyPage.aspx.resx and/or MyPage.aspx.{culturename}.resx in the special directory **App_LocalResource**.

If you like Global Resources instead of local, use the special directory **App_GlobalResource**
to hold a resource file called MyResourceFileName.resx and call:

```
ctrl.Text= (string)GetGlobalResourceObject(“MyResourceFileName”, “myGlobalKey”);
```

[copied from a blog about localization in the code behind](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p185/localising-programmatically-in-asp-net-code-behind)

--
PS the reason that Attributes.Add("meta:resourcekey", "label") doesn't work is that "meta:resourcekey" isn't a real attribute and its use in the aspx is not really valid aspx markup - rather it's a preprocessing directive that causes the compiler to turn it into a longer list of attributes name/value pairs, based on what you've put in your resource file.

Answer (score 3):

The approach of trying to assign a `meta:resourcekey` attribute will not work simply because they are treated specially by the page parser, and replaced before the page lifecycle code even really begins.

But `meta:resourcekey` is basically a declarative replacement for the code equivalent of accessing local resource files. In other words:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" meta:resource-key="MyResourceKey" />
```

is equivalent to:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" Text="<%$ Resources: myResXFile, MyResourceKey %>" />
```

is equivalent to the code:

```
MyLabel.Text = Resources.MyResXFile.MyResourceKey;
```

It looks like you're already dealing with your label in the code if you're trying to assign attributes to it. Why not set it's value in the code?

Comment: That's not entirely true, because the first method using the meta attribute, will implicitly bind the set of "Key.Property" lines in the resource file. The second two methods require explicitly identifying the properties where the keys apply.